# Getting started help. C++ and compiling in codeblocks

Tags: c++, codeblocks

Sorry for what is most likely a very 'newbie' question, but I'm having a slight problem with running C++ code in code::blocks. A little bit about what I'm doing then, basically I'm following Bjarne Stroustrup's 'Programming: Principles and Practice using C++'. I'm really just starting the book, and to do so I am using code::blocks on Ubuntu 12.04. Anyway for the first hello world example I did the following:

first set up a new project -> selected console application -> selected C++ as my language -> entered in the name of the project -> selected GNU GCC Compiler (from reading and searching around this might be the problem) -> and finally entered the code.

I've also made sure to properly download and save the 'std_lib_facilities.h' header file. After doing all this I entered in the simple hello world code as shown below. On building the code it produced the following warning (no errors though): '#warning This file includes at least one deprecated or antiqued header which may be removed...' which when clicked on leads me to 'backward_warning.h'. However I can still run the code which produces the hello world to appear fine, like it should. This might imply I don't have a problem, but with the warning still present, I was just wondering if there is a fix or if it even means anything is wrong, as I don't want to find that in later examples this proves to be a problem. This might all seem like a silly question, but I'm new to C++ and still quite new to programming in general, so apologies in advance. And here is my code:

```
#include "../std_lib_facilities.h"

int main()
{
cout<<"Hello World";
return 0;
}
```

Comment: What files are included in the header you've got?

Comment: @chris presumably it is [this header](http://www.stroustrup.com/Programming/std_lib_facilities.h)

Comment: It's probably this one: `#include <ext/hash_map>`, seeing as how it's in a compiler-specific section and the book might be older than a newer version of it.

Comment: @chris Files included in the header? Not sure I quite understand sorry, is the header not just one file that you can almost 'import'? The header is of Stroustrup's site. And when I open it up it has a load of includes, such as include <iostream>. sorry if that's not what you mean

Comment: @Niall, Try commenting out the block in `../std_lib_facilities.h` between the first and second `//--------------------------------------------`

Comment: @chris I tried that, and then built my code again but I seemed to get errors within that header after doing so.

Comment: @Niall, Ah, I see what you mean. Commenting more and more out at that point starts turning into a pretty bad solution compared to fixing it now and never having to worry about it.

Comment: @chris Ah I seemed to have got it, or well I hope I do! But anyway, I commented out what you said to do, and followed the errors that appeared, which said that within the header there was another section of code using hash at this line: `template<> struct hash<String>`. I commented this out and the warning appears to be gone for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is most likely `<hash_map>` or `<ext/hash_map>`.

A replacement would be C++11's `<unordered_map>`, or C++03's `<tr1/unordered_map>`.

If you are using GCC, you can access C++11 functionality by adding the `std=c++0x` compilation flag. This will allow you to use `<unordered_map>`.

Comment: OK, but this won't impact the rest of the book's examples? I wouldn't be better of leaving this alone then?

Comment: @Niall, I suspect you won't be using hash maps for quite a while. By then, you'll easily be able to pick through the details of what you need.

Comment: @Niall I have to admit I haven't read the book, so I don't know... you can always disable the warning, but be aware that the deprecated code might just disappear in a newer version of the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

The examples in this book might be very old for your Ubuntu. Try to replace the deprecated headers with the new ones.

Comment: Yeah I seen a suggestion like that elsewhere, would that mean replacing the `#include <exit/hash_map>` with the newer version?

Comment: One problem is that `hash_map` turned out as `unordered_map` in the final standard. I would just remove that part of the include file for now, and solve this later (when you actually need a hash_map/unordered_map).

Answer (score 0):

This simple "Hello World" app only needs one include directive:

```
#include <iostream>
```

I suggest avoid using "std_lib_facilities.h" until you need it.